# A file does not compile (with enumitem.sty)

Tags: errors, enumitem

The following does not compile. What is the error?

```
\documentclass[english]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{wideenum}{enumerate}{4}
\setlist[wideenum]{wide}

\begin{document}

\begin{wideenum}
\item abbreviation
\item xxx dfjks fjk kjfds fjkds fjkds fjks jf djks fdjks kjfds kjfsddfjks
fjk kjfds fjkds fjkds fjks jf djks fdjks kjfds kjfsddfjks fjk kjfds
fjkds fjkds fjks jf djks fdjks kjfds kjfsddfjks fjk kjfds fjkds fjkds
fjks jf djks fdjks kjfds kjfsddfjks fjk kjfds fjkds fjkds fjks jf
djks fdjks kjfds kjfsddfjks fjk kjfds fjkds fjkds fjks jf djks fdjks
kjfds kjfsddfjks fjk kjfds fjkds fjkds fjks jf djks fdjks kjfds kjfsd
\end{wideenum}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not sure what the cause of this problem is, but replacing `\item` with `\item[]` is a quick fix.

Comment: `\setlist[wideenum]{wide,label*=\arabic*}`?

Answer (score 3):

The error is a "undefined label", so you can supply a label with `\item[]` as Mico suggest, or you can define a label:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{wideenum}{enumerate}{4}
\setlist[wideenum]{label*=\arabic*.,wide}
\begin{document}
\begin{wideenum}
\item abbreviation
\item dfjks \ldots
\end{wideenum}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @MarcvanDongen you were 9 seconds faster !